# Como puedo devolver un array multiplicado por 2?

Tags: javascript

Hola estoy intentando que este código me devuelva un array añadido en la función para luego ser multiplicado * 2 , he intentado lograrlo de esta manera pero hasta ahora he logrado que solo salgan los array que coloco en la función pero sin exito de lograr que se multipliquen por cualquier número en este caso necesito que se multipliquen por dos para duplicar su valor

````
function duplicar (array){
  var resultado = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
   if(array[i] >= resultado){
   resultado.push(array)
     return resultado;
     
   }  
    }
} document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = duplicar ([1,3,4,5]); ```
````

Comment: Stein, estas teniendo varias respuestas, y en una has comentado que te ha funcionado y lo has agradecido. En este sitio los agradecimientos se demuestran aceptando las respuestas que mejor nos han funcionado. Para aprender a aceptar respuestas visita este [enlace](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/263200) y así colaborarás en el buen funcionamiento del sitio, mostrando a la comunidad la buena respuesta o la que mejor te ha funcionado. Léete tambien [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio, gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No acabo de entender tu pregunta al 100%, si lo que quieres es una función a la que le pasas un array y que devuelva ese mismo array multiplicando cada elemento por 2, sería así:

```js
function duplicar(valores) {
  var resultado = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < valores.length; i++) {
    resultado.push(valores[i] * 2);
  }
  return resultado;
}

console.log(duplicar([1, 2, 3]));
```

Comment: muchas gracias ! , esto era lo que buscaba por alguna razón use if y veo que no se necesita, excelente tu respuesta compañero

Comment: @Stein El uso de `if` es para validar que la posición que se esta evaluando no sea nula. Si la lógica de tu programa no permite que te lleguen vacios, no es necesario.

Answer (score 2):

Es muy sencillo, usando `funciones array` como el `map` con el cual puedes puedes trabajar con cada objeto

```js
const duplicar = (array) => array.map(item => item * 2);

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = duplicar([1,3,4,5]);
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ese código no es correcto para lo que quieres. Por ejemplo comparas un item del array con el array resultado completo, ni le veo el sentido ni es correcto, luego haces el return dentro del bucle, no es lógico en tu problema.
Te doy un par de soluciones.
La más elemental, y a mi juicio más sencilla de entender

```
function duplicar (array){
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = array[i]*2 ;
   }  
  return array;
} 
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = duplicar ([1,3,4,5]);
```

Aunque en realidad el return está de más, porque el array en el argumento se pasa por referencia (la función recibe la dirección del array), no por valor.

```
function duplicar (array){
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = array[i]*2 ;
   }  
}
let lista = [1,3,4,5];
duplicar(lista);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = lista;
```

Otra usando el método map del objeto array

```
function duplicar (lista){
 return lista.map((v)=>v*2);
} 
lista = [1,3,4,5];
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = duplicar(lista);
```

Realmente esta última sería más sencilla aún:

```
lista = [1,3,4,5];
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = lista.map(function(v){return >v*2;});
```

Te pongo la función del map descrita con => y con function, para que veas dos formas de los mismo. Ambas soluciones son iguales.
El método map crea otro array a partir de cada elemento del array original. El argmento de map es una función que devuelve cada elemento del array original ya transformado. Esta función recorre el array y puede llevar tres argumentos: valor del elemento actual del array, índice actual y array completo. En este caso como solo se necesita el valor solo uso el primero.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta, muy completa y sincera, estoy aun aprendiendo javascript y se me dificulta mucho a veces la lógica cuando debo usar un loop con condicional de if o algo parecido pero me lo haz aclarado bastante aun tengo algunas dudas pero con el trayecto me iré preguntando hehehe muchas gracias @juan

Comment: Si quieres puedes añadir este sitio a tu lista de recursos de aprendizaje: [Javascript desde cero](https://javascript.espaciolatino.com)